# javascript only dial with percentage counter

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

I'm developing a dial that a user can interact with via ontouch events for an iPad only project. The user can set it to a percentage and I need to have that percentage number displayed outside of the dial.

**I can't use jquery**, believe me I wish I could, it has to be done with just javascript and CSS. I've looked at this [code here](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) but, like I stated before, I can't use jquery.

I've been modifying this http://eskimoblood.github.io/jim-knopf/ and I'm close. However I cannot get the number to display outside of the dial. Ideally I would have the percentage and the dial in separate elements so I can move and style them independently of each other. Basically I cannot get the number to display outside of the dial and I'm hoping to cut down on the code cause I will only need one stye of dial at a time. Any suggestions on where I can look?